# What is the difference between Socket and ServerSocket?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

If `Socket` represents client side and `ServerSocket` represents server side, why `Socket.read` reads the data from server side? I'm really confused, Can you please clarify it to me?

Answer (score 56):

(I post this answer because I always feel it's important to make the logic right.)

I suggest you take a look at the following sample.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Admittedly, when carrying out TCP/IP communication, all the necessary information can be provided by the `Socket` class alone for the sole purpose of communication. No matter it is on server side or client side.

As you can see from the above link, **server side** use the following code to acquire its own `Socket` instance. That is, **another** socket is created on the **same server local port and the client port pair**.

[image]

Then, server use this `Socket` instance to talk to the client.

And to make the picture complete, below code snippet shows **clien**t's `Socket` instance.

[image]

**So if `Socket` can do it all already, why do we still need the `ServerSocket`?**

This is because of the working paradigm of communication over TCP/IP protocol.

When 2 programs talk over TCP/IP, usually one will *passively* listen/wait on a `<IP:port>` and the other one will *actively* connect to it.

**So you can see, at this very `starting phase` of the communication, the 2 sides have very different behaviors. So 2 different classes are used to reflect this difference.**

- `Socket` class encapsulates the behavior of the active side. (a.k.a. the client)
- `ServerSocket` class encapsulates the behavior of the passive side (a.k.a. the server)

Once the `ServerSocket` accomplished its listening task and `detected` an incoming connection, it will `accept()` it and create a new `Socket` instance to facilitate the communication.

Similarily, in `java.nio` package, you will find `ServerSocketChannel` and `SocketChannel` classes. And still, they behave like this:

```
ServerSocketChannel -------------> SocketChannel
                      accept()
```

So, to some extent, I agree with @JohnK as he pointed out in the comment, `it's more or less just a 6-letter difference`.

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Comment: @KarlRichter It's for better high-lighting.

Comment: "That is, another socket is created on another port." This might be misleading since the new socket uses the same port as the one the server is listening on. If your `ServerSocket` listens on port 443, the new `Socket` will also use port 443 and the client's ephemeral port.

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. You can convince yourself by cloning and starting [this simple server](https://gitlab.com/bullbytes/simple_socket_based_server) which uses `ServerSocket`. Doing `curl -k "https://localhost:8443/"` will show that the `socket` (created from `accept()`) for sending TCP packets to the client and the `serverSocket` used for accepting new client connections both use 8443 as the local port. The code in question is [here](https://gitlab.com/bullbytes/simple_socket_based_server/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bullbytes/simpleserver/Start.java#L68).

Comment: @MatthiasBraun Thanks. You are correct. I refined the answer. It is the pair of ports defines the socket. The link in my answer also details that.

Comment: Would it be better if the `Socket` class were named as `Connection`? It seems `ServerSocket` is really one socket (one IP + one port), whereas upon successfully creation, `Socket` is actually a TCP connection containing two sockets, i.e. both the client and the server endpoints.

Answer (score 12):

> *why socket.read reads the data from serverside*

Because it is reading the data **sent** by the server through the **network**, it is not reading directly the server filesystem or resouces ( db , ram or anything like that )  it is reading the data that was already processed by the ServerSocket.

Think about the Socket as your web browser and the ServerSocket as the remote webserver.

When you request an image, page, etc, the webserver ( The ServerSocket ) writes the bytes to the client, in turn the client has to read them ( to know what the webserver sent right? ) and process them by displaying them to the final user.

The same happend with ServerSocket/Socket but at a lower level. The socket **reads** information from the ServerSocket.

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 10):

First of all, let's clarify what IS `Socket` look like: in a common case, `Socket` is a concatenation of IP and port via `:`, for example: `127.0.0.1:8080`.

So, you decided to make client-server application using `Socket`. There's nothing too much complicated. Here's short explanation about making connection between `client` and `server`:

1. First of all, let's clarify that fact, that our `client` have his own `Socket` and knows `server` IP address and port. For `server` there are provided only `ServerSocket` and port. In both cases port are the same number between 0 and 65535.
2. So, we decided to connect our `client` to our `server`:

   - `client` creates his `Socket clientSocket` object with known IP and port of our `server`.
   - `server` got incoming connection request with his `ServerSocket.accept()` method, which generates new `Socket newClientSocket` object (still on a `server` side (!) ).
   - Further data exchanging goes via `clientSocket` and `newClientSocket` objects (not between `clientSocket` and `ServerSocket`).

[Here](https://codethat.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/scheme.png) is almost perfect picture to understand the basic connection process (keep in mind, that `Socket` object on `Client` at this picture - same objects).

After you've made this simple structure, you need to open two streams on both `Client.clientSocket` and `Server.newClientSocket` sides for reading and writing information.

Comment: Your *Here* link led me to the original post. https://codethat.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/coffee-time-with-java-part-1-sockets     It is a wonderful socket/serversocket crash tutorial .... Thanks!

Comment: that image you attached cleared almost all my doubts. thank you so much.

Comment: @SuppieRK Assuming I have 100 Server.newClientSocket objects, all of themwill use the same server port for sending and receiving data to their corresponding client-sockets ?

Answer (score 8):

**java.net.ServerSocket**

> This class implements server sockets. A server socket waits for
>   requests to come in over the network. It performs some operation based
>   on that request, and then possibly returns a result to the requester.

**java.net.Socket**

> This class implements client sockets (also called just "sockets"). A
>   socket is an endpoint for communication between two machines.

Answer (score 1):

ServerSocket is again a Socket with additional features of server endpoint. The server features includes listening to the port and accepting an incoming connection etc...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

`ServerSocket` is created to `bind` to a port and `listen` for a `connect` from a client. So, a server just waits for a conversation and doesn't start one.

`ClientSocket` is created to `connect` to a `listen`ing server. The client initiates the connection.

Example: Think of an inbound call center as an example. These services are servers. They don't initiate a call but wait for a call to come in from clients. Once the calls are in, they can engage in a two way conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's reading what has been sent to you *by* the server.

Answer (score 0):

`Socket` is for the client side and `ServerSocket` is for the server side.